# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" in modal script

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I know this has been asked like a thousand times but I couldn't find an existing post that fixed my problem, so I apologize in advance. I'm still learn all this and have been testing a few things here and there to practice. When trying to set up a modal script for images in a site I'm working on, I ran into the issue in the title.

I've tried placing an 'if (img)' statement before the 'img.modal' function as suggested in another post. That clears the error out, but doesn't fix anything.

HTML

```
  <img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" />

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" />

        <div id="caption">Snow</div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

When clicking the thumbnail image (myImg), it should bring up an modal containing the enlarged image (img01). But when I click on the image, nothing happens. Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: How is `myImg` defined?

Comment: And how is `modal` defined

Comment: @Geshode Oops missed that line while copying, editted it in there.

Answer (score 0):

Because, javascript can not get element with id = ‘myImg’
Cause in html do not have any element with that id 
let img will be null

Answer (score 0):

Fix up your code a little. This seems to work how you expect.

Click the little image to open, and the 'x' to close.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img class="modal-content" id="myImg" width="100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /> 

<div id="myModal" class="modal"> 
  <span class="close">&times;</span> 
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01" width="200" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /> 
  <div id="caption">Snow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aw that makes sense, I'll give that a try once I get home.

Comment: Well I added in the lines that you suggested but it's still not working correctly. It's different now, it made the image zoomed in. Probably the size it would be if the modal worked. Could an issue in the CSS interfere with the script?

Comment: Yes it could, this script is just changing the styles of the elements. Yet, the script's style will be added inline so it will override the CSS is a file.

Comment: Well I have the script running in an external file. I'll look through the css and fidget with it a bit. When I figure it out I'll update the topic. Thank you so much :)